# error in fstrim cron job on ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm getting this error `"/bin/sh: 1: fstrim: not found"` from a cron job.

which seems to be this one and seems to be a default cron job shipped by ubuntu:

```
/etc/cron.weekly# cat fstrim 
#!/bin/sh
# trim all mounted file systems which support it
/sbin/fstrim --all || true
```

if i run that script directly i get no error and it seems to work fine :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me (just went and poked around too). Is it possible you somehow ended up with another cron job that's giving you that error and perhaps it's not `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`?

Where do you see that error?

You could try copying that script into /etc/cron.hourly and see if the error occurs every hour. The logs might explain more (`/var/log/syslog`).

It ***seems*** like it shouldn't be possible to get that error with the stock cron script if you can run it by hand and the `fstrim` command exists. All Ubuntu distributions are shipping with that script and probably Debian. It looks identical to mine.

Comment: damn, there was an other daily cron in `/etc/cron.d/kernel` which was probably added by the hosters xenial image.. will ask their support and most likely delete it ;)